# How to write to an Excel column using a list of lists using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have this Excel (this is a preview but it's structured like that for the entire Excel)

[image]

I have a list of lists where the food name is associated to the ID, here's a preview:

```
id_food_list = [['6737', 'Apple'], ['6733', 'Cheese'], ['6731', 'Tomatos']]
```

It would like this:

[image]

Since there's a column I'm ignoring (and one at the bottom too), I'm looking to do something like:

`if sub-list[1] == column value --> write sub-list[0] to corresponding 'ID' column`

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: The last picture I posted

Answer (score 0):

I created the 'Book1.xlsx' as shown in your first figure.

```
import pandas as pd

id_food_list = [['6737', 'Apple'], ['6733', 'Cheese'], ['6731', 'Tomatos']]

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', index_col=0)
for sublist in id_food_list:
    df.loc[sublist[1], 'ID'] = sublist[0]

df.to_excel('Book1.xlsx', index=False)
```

Since I assigned the first column as index column of the dataframe by `index_col=0`, the `loc` can set the value by indexing the row and column names.

Comment: Am I supposed to see some change in my Excel file or do I have to use another function write it? Because the script runs but nothing changes in the excel file.

Comment: Oh~ I just added the export part to the 'Book1.xlsx'.

Comment: I thought you suppose to know how to check the data inside python before export. Are you familiar with use inside a console?

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Is the answer OK for you?